# PHP Lithium framework - How to use xSQL FUNC in model

Tags: php, lithium

For example, in PHP Lithium framework, if we want to create a new user object and add it to db, we can use this -

```
$model = 'app\models\Users';
$user = $model::create();
$user->user_guid = uniqid ();

$user->save ();
```

Now I want to use MySQL FUNC `UUID()` to replace uniqid() in PHP, the SQL is similar to this :

```
INSERT INTO users SET user_guid=UUID();
```

How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `lithium\util\String` has a uuid() generator:

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/util/String.php#L61

(I'm afraid my lithium-fu is a bit too rusty to remember how to use an sql expression, but I'm pretty certain that is possible too.)

Comment: But, is UUID() better performance? To leverage the computing between PHP and MySQL, I think better to use UUID().

Comment: Using lithium's uuid() is a bit slower but it removes cpu cycles from your db server, so scales better.

Comment: True, let me check the URL. Thanks.

Comment: This is a choice, but not what I am looking for, even so it's a valid way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some specific SQL functions like `NOW()` or `UUID()` you should be able to use them using the following notation:

```
$user->user_guid = (object) 'UUID()';
```

This way, the string won't be "escaped".